# Excel to PowerPoint PasteSpecial and Keep Source Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to copy and paste a range from an Excel document into a PowerPoint slide.

It is copying the range as an image rather than keeping source formatting.

```
oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim oPPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
On Error Resume Next
Set XLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

Windows("File1.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B3:N9").Select
Selection.Copy
oPPTApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (2)
oPPTApp.ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate
oPPTApp.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject
oPPTApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 35
oPPTApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 150
```

Comment: which version of Office you run? your code (except some missing lines) looks and works fine. I have OLE Shape with excel range in PP presentation as required. All formatting is kept as in source range...

Comment: I'm using 2010. Everything works except when it copies over, it copies some borders of the Excel range. I need to copy with source formatting without all the borders of the cell.

Comment: is it possible when you do so manually, without vba? I'm not sure... I think you need to change cells borders formatting in your source excel file.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I tried it on PowerPoint using keep source formatting and it worked.

Comment: can you upload a screen shots of what you have and what you need?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/MrmwBo0.png

Comment: two options for you: 1) whiten cells borders in excel before copying, 2) copy exact range of the table without additional unnecessary cells on the left

Comment: Problem is, my tables aren't formatted into perfect rectangular shapes.

Comment: You could then still use option 1 or option 1A) fill cells with white colour

Comment: But one of the reasons I want to copy and paste with format is so I can still edit the values in powerpoint

Answer (score 4):

Let’s break this problem into a few different parts:

- Creating the PowerPoint Application
- Copying the Charts Pasting the
- Charts as the right format.

Now looking at your code, you are pretty much good to go on the first two. It’s pasting the object that is causing the problem. Let’s explore the different ways to paste.

**USING THE EXECUTEMSO METHOD:**

When we use this method it’s like we are right-clicking on the slide and pasting the object on to the slide. Now while this method is a completely valid way to paste, achieving this in VBA can be a little challenging. The reason why is because it is extremely volatile, and we must slow down our script to a snail’s pace!

[image]

To implement this method along with any of its different options, do the following:

```
'Create a new slide in the Presentation, set the layout to blank, and paste range on to the newly added slide.
 Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)

   'WARNING THIS METHOD IS VERY VOLATILE, PAUSE THE APPLICATION TO SELECT THE SLIDE
    For i = 1 To 5000: DoEvents: Next
    PPTSlide.Select

   'WARNING THIS METHOD IS VERY VOLATILE, PAUSE THE APPLICATION TO PASTE THE OBJECT
    For i = 1 To 5000: DoEvents: Next
    PPTApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"
    PPTApp.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus

'PASTE USING THE EXCUTEMSO METHOD - VERY VOLATILE

'Paste As Source Formatting
'PPTApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"

'Paste as Destination Theme
'PPTApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteDestinationTheme"

'Paste as Embedded Object
'PPTApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteAsEmbedded"

'Paste Excel Table Source Formatting
'PPTApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting"

'Paste Excel Table Destination Theme
'PPTApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableDestinationTableStyle"
```

Now if you look at my code, I had to pause it two different times to make sure it would work. This is because VBA will move way too fast otherwise and all that will happen is it will paste all the objects on the first slide! **If we are only doing one paste we are usually safe without putting in the pauses, but the minute you want to go to a new slide put the pauses in!**

**USING THE REGULAR PASTE METHOD:**

When we use this method, it’s like we are pressing Crtl+V and it will simply paste the object as a regular shape in PowerPoint. The regular shape means the default paste type in PowerPoint. Here is how we can implement a simple paste method:

```
'PASTE USING PASTE METHOD - NOT AS VOLATILE

'Use Paste method to Paste as Chart Object in PowerPoint
 PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste
```

**USING THE PASTE SPECIAL METHOD:**

When we use this method it’s like we are pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on the keyboard and we get all sorts of different options of how to paste it. **It ranges from a picture all the way to an embedded object that we can link back to the source workbook.**

[image]

**With the paste special method, sometimes we will still have to pause our scripts.** The reason why is like the reason I mentioned above, VBA is volatile. **Just because we copy it doesn’t mean it will make it to our clipboard. This problem can pop up and then disappear at the same time, so our best bet is to have a pause in our script to give VBA enough time to put the information in the clipboard.** It usually doesn’t have to be a long pause but only a second or 2. Here is how we implement the paste special method with the different options we can use:

```
'PASTE USING PASTESPECIAL METHOD - NOT AS VOLATILE

'Paste as Bitmap
 PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteBitmap

'Paste as Default
 PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteDefault

'Paste as EnhancedMetafile
 PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile

'Paste as HTML - DOES NOT WORK WITH CHARTS
 PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteHTML

'Paste as GIF
 PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteGIF

'Paste as JPG
 PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteJPG

'Paste as MetafilePicture
 PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture

'Paste as PNG
 PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPastePNG

'Paste as Shape
 PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteShape

'Paste as Shape, display it as an icon, change the icon label, and make it a linked icon.
 PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteShape, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconLabel:="Link to my Chart", Link:=msoTrue

'Paste as OLEObject and it is linked.
 PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse
```

With all that being said, if you paste an object as an OLEObject with a link most of the time the formatting comes over with it. Unless you have a special theme that only exist in Excel, that’s where you get into trouble. I ran into this problem when I was taking a chart from Excel To Word, but the Excel chart had a custom theme.

**Here is your code, rewritten so that it will paste an object using the source format and setting the dimensions of it.** I hope you don't mind me readjusting some of your code to make it a little more concise.

```
Sub PasteRangeIntoPowerPoint()

'Declare your variables
Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim oPPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim Rng As Range

'Get the PowerPoint Application, I am assuming it's already open.
Set oPPTApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

'Set a reference to the range you want to copy, and then copy it.
Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:N9")
    Rng.Copy

'Set a reference to the active presentation.
Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.ActivePresentation

'Set a reference to the slide you want to paste it on.
Set oPPTSlide = oPPTFile.Slides(3)

    'WARNING THIS METHOD IS VERY VOLATILE, PAUSE THE APPLICATION TO SELECT THE SLIDE
    For i = 1 To 5000: DoEvents: Next
    oPPTSlide.Select

    'WARNING THIS METHOD IS VERY VOLATILE, PAUSE THE APPLICATION TO PASTE THE OBJECT
    For i = 1 To 5000: DoEvents: Next
    oPPTApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"
    oPPTApp.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus
    For i = 1 To 5000: DoEvents: Next

    'Set the dimensions of your shape.
    With oPPTApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
        .Left = 35
        .Top = 150
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: One `DoEvents` after `ExecuteMso` seems to be enough for my Office 2013.

Answer (score 2):

For that case, I have always been happy using `Copy picture` in Excel. To get it, click the arrow next to `Copy`.
In VBA, it translates to

```
Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
```

In older versions of Excel (2003 and previous) you need to click `Shift+Edit` to get that option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
oPPTApp.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteDefault
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution instead of using the `Shapes.PasteSpecial` method:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19187572/1467082

```
PPTApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting"
```

This does not create a link to the Excel document, it embeds a local copy of the document in the PowerPoint Presentation. I think I understand this is your requirement.

Comment: Hello David, I have been trying hard to resolve it, whenever i use **ExecuteMso** method, macro is failing with different errors each time, but with **pastespecial** method macro runs successfully, but it wont give the sourcce format, I am pasting total 40 shapes from 20 excel sheets. please help.

Comment: @expfresh Please submit a **new** question with the details of your particular problem, including the code you are attempting to use and description of error(s) and which lines raise the errors.  Please submit this as a new question, so that the entire SO community can attempt to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a code of mine that Keeps Source Formatting:

```
Sub SigAcc()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim myPresentation As Object
Set myPresentation = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Set objPPApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    Set PPSlide = myPresentation.ActivePresentation.Slides(2)


lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("The worksheet you would like to copy").Range("Letter of longest column (E.I. "A")" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For p = PPSlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set myShape = PPSlide.Shapes(p)
    If myShape.Type = msoPicture Then myShape.Delete
    Next



Set myPresentation = myPresentation.ActivePresentation
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(2)
On Error Resume Next


'assigning range into variable
Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet to copy").Range("A1:C" & lastrow)
On Error Resume Next

'If we have already opened powerpoint
Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(Class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'If Powerpoint is not opened
If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(Class:="Powerpoint.Application")


r.Copy

'to paste range
PPApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial
  Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
    'Set position:
      myShape.left = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 2 - ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 2
      myShape.Top = 80
PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate


'to clear the cutcopymode from clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful if you would explain what the basic idea is and what the code does instead of 'just' providing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was very annoyed that Excel wouldn't allow pasting the table with the CommandBars method. Moreover, none of the suggested solutions seemed to work for me.

Now, I have found a satisfying solution using the GetPastedShape function from Jamie Garroch, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35059114/vba-powerpoint-name-a-table). At least it is applicable in cases where you already have a formatted table in place and only need to update the values.

The basic idea is to paste the table unformatted (which works fine), copy every single cell from the unformatted table to the desired formatted table that is already in place in your PPT. Afterwards the unformatted table is deleted. So when you're running the code you won't take notice that there was a temporary "support" table in your PPT.

Applied to your code the solution looks as follows:

```
Windows("File1.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B3:N9").Select
Selection.Copy

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

Tab_unformatted = GetPastedShape.Name ' this is the Function from Jamie Garroch

For i = 1 To UBound(Tab_formatted, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(Tab_formatted, 2)
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Tab_formatted").Table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(Tab_unformatted).Table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    Next
Next

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(Tab_unformatted).Delete
```