# VBA code to copy excel data to existing powerpoint table

Tags: vba, powerpoint, excel-2013

I have code that is successful at conditionally copying a specified range of cells, opens a previously saved PowerPoint template, and opens the correct slide. I need to code the equivalent of (right-click, paste special K). I think I'm close, but just need help with the last bit.

```
Sub CreateStaffTemplate()
With Worksheets("Feb")
    Select Case .Range("C20").Value
        Case .Range("B4").Value:    .Range("B6:D15").Copy
        Case .Range("F4").Value:    .Range("F6:H15").Copy
        Case .Range("J4").Value:    .Range("J6:L15").Copy
        Case .Range("N4").Value:    .Range("N6:P15").Copy
    End Select
End With

Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myShapeRange As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim SlideNum As Integer
Dim ppTable As PowerPoint.Table

Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application
PPT.Visible = True
PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:="C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Staff Meeting Template.pptm"
PPT.Activate
PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Select
Set ppTable = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(2).Table
ppTable.??????????????
```

I've searched for a few hours and haven't found what I need or something that translates.

Comment: Can't record macros in PowerPoint. Recording the same function in excel gives me the following (which does not translate to PowerPoint): selection.pastespecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:+xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: @JasonAller I'm sorry, either I'm not being clear or my rudimentary understanding of VBA is preventing me from applying your suggestion. The goal is to house the macro in excel with the rest of the code, grab the cells, open the pptx file, paste into the existing table.

Comment: Sorry for the earlier confusion. I've found other references to using `PPT.Commandbars.ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting")`. Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338295/excel-to-powerpoint-vba-pastespecial-keep-source-formatting even though they are trying to paste a chart.