# Pasting a large table into separate slides by Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I would like to paste a table from excel to power point using VBA. However, as I have dynamic range therefore I would like to create slides with 15 rows only for better visualization. For example, it will paste row 1 to row 15 into slide number 1 then row 1, and  row 16 to row 29 into slide number 2 and so on. Here row 1 is the header of the table. I have attached the code where I can create only one slide. I would highly appreciate if anyone can help me.

```vb
Sub SortingandSlidecreation()

    Dim pptName As String
    Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim myPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim slds As PowerPoint.Slides
    Dim sld As PowerPoint.slide
    Dim pptextbox As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim oLayout As CustomLayout
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim y As Workbook, LastRow&
    Dim r As Range


    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("SortedTable")

    'This will open a PowerPoint template (I didn't attach the function) 
    pptName = openDialog()                                              
    Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set myPres = ppt.Presentations.Open(pptName)
    Set slds = myPres.Slides

    ' creating slides at the end of the template 
    Set sld = slds.Add(myPres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)

    'Here data is selected for pasting
    Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SortedTable").Range("A1:L" & LastRow)
    r.Copy
    sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0
    sld.Shapes(1).Top = 100
    sld.Shapes(1).Left = 100

    'Here title of the table is added
    Set pptextbox = sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 22, 60, 700, 60)

    With pptextbox.TextFrame
        .TextRange.Text = "Summary of Current Projects"  
        .TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
        .TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial(Headings)"
        .TextRange.Font.Size = 20
        .TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 51, 102)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the title the same for all slides, and all you need help with is just to create the several slides? Also are the columns for the data A to L?

Comment: @AAA title will be same as I will paste the same table. As I have mentioned first row is the header of columns A to L. Therefore, it will be pasted in every slides without any change. Final goal is to put a table into several slides if the table contains rows more than 15.

Comment: have you tried the answer below?

Comment: @AAA It works perfectly now. I have one more question. How can can define/fix the size of the table in PPT? The size is changing all the time and font became really small.

Comment: Do you need to edit the pasted content in Powerpoint? If not, why not paste as a bitmap (`DataType:=1)? Or just use normal paste and Source Formatting

Comment: It is always useful to have that option to edit. Bitmap can provide the option to paste in a visible size however, without edit option. In the normal paste option, I have to change the size manually . That's why I was asking how to paste it as editable shapes with user defined size.

Comment: See whether [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338295/excel-to-powerpoint-vba-pastespecial-keep-source-formatting) can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your current definition of `LastRow`. Then delete everything after your `Set slds = myPres.Slides` line and paste this code instead.

```
Dim LastRow as Long, i as Long, j as Integer, rngH as Range, wss as Worksheet
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngH = ws.Range("A1:L1") 'Header Row
i = 2
Set wss = wb.Worksheets.Add

Do While i <= LastRow
    j = Application.Min(i + 13, LastRow)
    Union(rngH, ws.Range("A" & i, ws.Range("L" & j))).Copy Destination:= wss.Range("A1")
    Set sld = slds.Add(myPres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
    wss.Range("A1:L" & j-i+2).Copy
    sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0
    sld.Shapes(1).Top = 100
    sld.Shapes(1).Left = 100

    'Here title of the table is added
    Set pptextbox = sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 22, 60, 700, 60)

    With pptextbox.TextFrame
        .TextRange.Text = "Summary of Current Projects"  
        .TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
        .TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial(Headings)"
        .TextRange.Font.Size = 20
        .TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 51, 102)
    End With
    i = j + 1
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wss.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set wss = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: it doesn't work properly. It can creates the first slides with 15 rows. However, in the second slide it pasted 29 rows instead of next 14. In the third slide it puts everything including empty cells. Currently my table has 39 rows. It seems it is doing accumulation using i=i+14. I debug the code, then it shows that it is selecting correctly however pasted wrongly.

Comment: @OliAK, yes I see the problem. Powerpoint can't paste non-contiguous ranges, it seems. So I have amended the code to paste to a temporary worksheet and then copy that worksheet instead.