# PowerPoint VBA to retain source formatting in destination PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following code to copy specific slides (based on tags) to a new presentation. I want to retain the formatting of the source presentation in the copied slides of the destination presentation.

**Current Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim strTagName As String
Dim strTagValue As String

strTagName = "pname"
strTagValue = "Azure"

Dim currentPresentation As Presentation
Dim newPresentation As Presentation
Dim s As Slide

' Save reference to current presentation
Set currentPresentation = Application.ActivePresentation

' Save reference to current slide
'Set currentSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

' Add new Presentation and save to a reference
Set newPresentation = Application.Presentations.Add

For Each s In currentPresentation.Slides
    If s.Tags(strTagName) = "Azure" Then

    s.Copy
    newPresentation.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")

    End If

Next

newPresentation.SaveAs (currentPresentation.Path & "\" & strTagValue & "_Quals Slides.pptx")

End Sub
```

Comment: Please take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338295/excel-to-powerpoint-pastespecial-and-keep-source-formatting

Comment: John Korchok - Thank you so much ! I was able to fix it using the pause script !! God Bless. I have added the working code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim strTagName As String
Dim strTagValue As String

strTagName = "pname"
strTagValue = "Azure"

Dim currentPresentation As Presentation
Dim newPresentation As Presentation
Dim s As Slide

' Save reference to current presentation
Set currentPresentation = Application.ActivePresentation

' Save reference to current slide
' Set currentSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

' Add new Presentation and save to a reference
Set newPresentation = Application.Presentations.Add

For Each s In currentPresentation.Slides
    If s.Tags(strTagName) = "Azure" Then

    s.Copy
    newPresentation.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
    For i = 1 To 5000: DoEvents: Next

    End If

Next

newPresentation.SaveAs (currentPresentation.Path & "\" & strTagValue & "_Quals Slides.pptx")

End Sub
```