# ppt.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting" method works ok while debugging, however it misses the target when macro runs

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to copy some ranges(Table) from excel to Powerpoint and want to keep the source formatting, hence using the  ppt.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting" method. It works ok when I run in the debugging mode, however when the code is run it gives unexpected results by pasting the Ranges to different locations. Please help.

```
Sub Updating_SCB_Service_Report()

ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path

Dim wbMD As Workbook
Dim MDPath As String

Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

MDPath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Automation").Range("C11")
Set wbMD = Workbooks.Open(MDPath)

Dim wb As Workbook

    myfile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Automation").Range("C10")
    Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set pptpre = ppt.Presentations.Open(Filename:=myfile)
    ppt.Visible = True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

''-------------------slide 3 -  Circuit Availability Exceptions
    Set pptslideCur = pptpre.Slides(3)
    wbMD.Worksheets("Exec Summ").Range("Circuit_Availability_Exceptions").Copy
    pptslideCur.Select
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"))
    
    ppt.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"
    'pptslideCur.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
    
    
    Set pptshp = pptslideCur.Shapes(pptslideCur.Shapes.Count)
    
    pptshp.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    pptshp.Top = 120.0064
    pptshp.Left = 420
    pptshp.Height = 65.1
    pptshp.Width = 348.0001
    Set pptshp = Nothing

'-------------------slide 4 -  Overall Operational Statistics Table

    Set pptslideCur = pptpre.Slides(4)

    pptslideCur.Select
    
    wbMD.Sheets("operational stats").Range("Table12[#All]").Copy
         If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Named range Table12[#All] is missing."
        Exit Sub
      End If

   ppt.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"
ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
    
    Set pptshp = pptslideCur.Shapes(pptslideCur.Shapes.Count)
    
    pptshp.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    
    pptshp.Top = 139.6323
    pptshp.Left = 5.999921
    pptshp.Height = 60.76669
    pptshp.Width = 357.3758

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'-------------------slide 4 -  Overall Operational Statistics charts

    Set pptslideCur = pptpre.Slides(4)
    pptslideCur.Select
    Set pptshp = pptslideCur.Shapes(3)
    pptshp.Select

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"))
    wbMD.Sheets("operational stats").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    pptslideCur.Select
    
    Set pptshp = pptslideCur.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteJPG, msoFalse)(1)
    pptshp.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    pptshp.Top = 109.9536
    pptshp.Left = 387.0305
    pptshp.Height = 184.8159
    pptshp.Width = 367.5938

    Set pptshp = Nothing
'-------------------slide 4 -  Overall Operational Statistics table

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Set pptslideCur = pptpre.Slides(4)
    pptslideCur.Select

    
    wbMD.Sheets("operational stats").Range("Table13[#All]").Copy
    pptslideCur.Select
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"))
    ppt.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"
    
    
    Set pptshp = pptslideCur.Shapes(pptslideCur.Shapes.Count)
    
    
    pptshp.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    pptshp.Top = 330
    pptshp.Left = 5.999921
    pptshp.Height = 72.6
    pptshp.Width = 357.3758

    Set pptshp = Nothing
```

Comment: It's worth a search first, because this question gets asked and answered every couple of weeks. I/O operations (copy, paste, open, save, etc.) run more slowly than your code. So you need to slow down your macro using Sleep, Wait or DoEvents.

Comment: Thank you john, Do events and Wait does not make any difference in the result.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues with copy-pasting slides with PasteSourceFormatting. Slides somehow got copied in a messed up way but everything worked fine while debugging.
However, basesd on mature's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53855668/3612740) this solution works for me:

```
Dim prsThis As Presentation
Dim prsThat As Presentation        
Dim sldThis As Slide

For i = 1 To prsThis.Slides.Count
  
  'copy slide (simplified)
  Set sldThis = prsThis.Slides(i)
  sldThis.Copy

  'paste
  prsThat.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"

  'wait until the slide shows up in the paste-presentation (this is what you need)
  prsThat.Application.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus
  Do
    For ii = 1 To 5000: DoEvents: Next
  Loop Until i >= prsThat.Slides.Count
  prsThat.Slides(i).Select

Next
```

Sidenotes:

- "i >= prsThat.Slides.Count" is my acceptance criteria for successfully pasted content. You may need to adapt it to your acceptance criteria
- Honestly, I did not have a look at your code in detail
- It's still a messy workaround, I know.