# VBA Copying all slides from all presentation from current directory into one active presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a problem that I'm struggling with for a couple of days.
I need to create an VBA macro that will copy all the slides (basically there will always be 1 slide) from each PPT presentation located in current directory, and paste them into the active presentation, preserving the whole style, formatting, fonts, picture, margins, everything.
I found code there:
http://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00746_Insert_all_slides_from_a_group_of_presentations_into_the_current_presentation.htm
but it doesn't preserve any style, so I was trying to change this fragment of code:

```
With ActivePresentation
        For x = 1 To UBound(vArray)
            If Len(vArray(x)) > 0 Then
                .Slides.InsertFromFile vArray(x), .Slides.Count
            End If
        Next
End With
```

and instead of using `.Slides.InsertFromFile vArray(x)` I wanted to use `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")`:

```
For x = 1 To UBound(vArray)
    If Len(vArray(x)) > 0 Then
        Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open(vArray(x), .Slides.Count, , False)
        objPresentation.Slides.Item(1).Copy
        currPresentation.Windows.Item(1).Activate
        currPresentation.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
        objPresentation.Close
            
    End If
Next
```

After the change it copies and pastes the slides with preserved formatting, but it copies the same slide x times. And then I read that's impossible to use `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")` to copy paste multiple slides from different presentations, because it will be always copying and pasting the same slide multiple times. I don't know if it's true, but I was trying to deal with it by creating multiple functions, and I always got the same result.

Then I read that I should use `Slides.Paste(1)`, but it doesn't preserve formatting, style, etc. so I should write manually function that will read information about fonts, style, formatting from the copied slide, and then while pasting it into the active one,  I should use the obtained information about the whole style - but it seems pretty hard and I do not know how to deal with that.

What is the best way there? Is there any chance to use
`Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")` to make it easy? Or maybe I'm going into totally wrong way?

Comment: Most likely you're getting multiple copies because VBA runs faster than I/O operations like the clipboard. Please see the first answer this post that shows how to slow down your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338295/excel-to-powerpoint-pastespecial-and-keep-source-formatting

Comment: @JohnKorchok Oh god, finally it works, I would probably never think about such a solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to John's answer on my problem, I found the solution - it was about to make a couple of pauses in a script in order to create enough time to put information to clipboard.
Right now this is how the for loop fragment of code looks like:

```
 For x = 1 To UBound(vArray)
            If Len(vArray(x)) > 0 Then
                Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open(vArray(x), .Slides.Count, , False)
                For i = 1 To 5000: DoEvents: Next
                objPresentation.Slides.Item(1).Copy
                currPresentation.Windows.Item(1).Activate
                For i = 1 To 5000: DoEvents: Next
                currPresentation.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
                For i = 1 To 5000: DoEvents: Next
                objPresentation.Close
                
            End If
        Next
```